# I am unable to record incoming voice in Nougat

Tags: android, sdk, media, mediarecorder, call-recording

I have developed an app for **call recording**, it was working so far nice and charm but now issues are coming like "incoming voice is not recording" in **NOUGAT** and the latest version, but some phones able to record a call from earphone or speaker on mode but not in normal mode, what would be the issues?

Answer (score 0):

How do you initialize your recorder?

This works for me for Nougat

```
    private void InitMediaRecorder()
    {
        _recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        _recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
        _recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
        _recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrNb);
        _recorder.SetOutputFile("Your_file_path");
        _recorder.Prepare();
    }
```

i assume you already set your Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: Have done the same, but not recording in some phones.